# Finding maven projects in a file structure

Tags: maven, batch-file, pom.xml, windows-scripting

I'm trying to write a Windows batch script, that given a path, will search recursively through that directory looking for maven projects. When it has found all the maven project paths, I want to run some of the maven plugins against each of these projects.

My problems is this, I'm not sure of the best way to find the projects roots since I use inheritance in my poms e.g.

```
-/project
    -pom.xml

    -/module1
       -pom.xml

    -/module2
       -pom.xml
```

Really I only want to find the path of **/project** in this instance and not of module1/2 e.g. where the parent pom is. At the moment I am searching for all `pom.xml` and working out which is the parent by scanning for `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in the xml file.

This works, but I can't help feeling that there are better methods of finding maven projects/parent poms.

Comment: you don't want to use powershell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy sounds good, but perhaps I can simplify your implementation. (tough for me to tell since you didn't show how you are currently doing it).

You could simply process the results of a recursive FINDSTR search with a FOR /F loop.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /mls "<packaging>pom</packaging>" "yourRootPath\pom.xml"'
) do echo %%~dpF
```